# onActivityResult is not getting called on back pressed

Tags: android

I am developing an app that goes from an activity to child activity and when back button is pressed it goes back to parent activity with two data i.e. row number and column number from a grid. The values are getting stored in the variables but when the back button is pressed the onActivityResult method is not getting called.

**Parent activity: onClick method**
`

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "beginning");
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GridActivity.class), REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });`
```

**Parent activity: onActivityResult method**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "receiving data");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "receiving data1");
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "result ok");
            if(data != null) {
                if (data.getIntExtra(COL_VALUE_TOKEN, 999) != 999) {
                    rowValue.setText(data.getIntExtra(ROW_VALUE_TOKEN, 999));
                    colValue.setText(data.getIntExtra(COL_VALUE_TOKEN, 999));
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "data not 999");
                } else {
                    rowValue.setText("-");
                    colValue.setText("-");
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "data 999");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Child activity: onClick method**

```
(findViewById(R.id.btn_ok)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

**Child activity: onBackPressed method**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(COL_VALUE_TOKEN, currentCol);
        intent.putExtra(ROW_VALUE_TOKEN, currentRow);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "sending data"+currentCol+currentRow);
        finish();
    }
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GridActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: It may be a because of how the back button is treated by the system.  Pressing back pops the current Activity off the stack to go back to a previous task whereas a call to finish() implies the Activity completing it's job.   My suggestion is to try maybe adding a button to your child Activity whose handler will do the call to setResut() and finish().

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing the same but there is no change. It is still not getting called. Log message in overridden onBackPressed method is getting printed but the ones in overridden onActivityResult method are not.

Comment: Are you sure u only have 1 onActivityResult, If you are using a fragment onActivityResult this might cause it